# Laravel scheduled task is not running with Cron, but works with artisan

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-5, cron

I have created scheduled task and it's running smoothley with command:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

Also I'm able to run it with command:

```
php /var/www/my.app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But when I try to run

```
* * * * * php /var/www/my.app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

as it described in Laravel doc's here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling
- nothing happends. If I remove

```
>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

(which is here to hide output). I'm getting:

```
Command not found
```

Thanks for any help.

Just in case I used this command to add line to cron:

```
(crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * php /var/www/bmon.app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1")| crontab -
```

Nice description here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/408611/how-to-remove-or-delete-single-cron-job-using-linux-command

Comment: Are you switching `/path/to/artisan schedule:run` to `/var/www/my.app/artisan schedule:run` in your CRON task?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in your cron:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/my.app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: this is how we have it setup, but i was going to add niceness to this, but i hear you dont want to use `nice` with php scripts.  Does that include runs using artisan?